# Using variables in a dictionary

Tags: python, variables, dictionary

I'm a beginner in Python and I started messing around with it.
I have this simple code:

```
def guess_number(Name,Gender):
    if Gender=='Male':
        Title='Mr.'
    else:
        Title='Ms.'
    number=int(raw_input("Hello " + Title + Name + ", guess what my favorite number is between 1-10"))
    if number==4:
        print number
        print "That's my favorite number!"
    else:
        print number
        print "Try Again!"
    return number

choice_dict=dict([(1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(4,0),(5,0),(6,0),(7,0),(8,0),(9,0),(10,0)])

for i in range(10):
    guess_number("Noam","Male")
    choice_dict[number]=choice_dict[number]+1

print choice_dict[1], choice_dict[2], choice_dict[3], choice_dict[4], choice_dict[5], choice_dict[6], choice_dict[7], choice_dict[8], choice_dict[9], choice_dict[10]
```

It's a simple process where in a function called "guess_number" it asks a person for a certain number between 1-10. It repeats the function 10 times and for each number chosen it will add +1 to the number in a dictionary, at the end it prints how many times was each number chosen.

For some reason I don't understand it tells me that "number" is not defined even though I returned the variable "number" in the function "guess_number".

What is missing?

Answer (score 4):

`number` is a variable local to the function `guess_number`. It does not exist outside of it. What you return is the value - not the variable itself, but its value - which you need to use, or assign to something. You can even assign it to a variable of the same name - as long as you understand it's *another* variable that just happens to have the same name:

```
number = guess_number("Noam", "Male")
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
guess_number("Noam","Male")
```

to

```
number = guess_number("Noam","Male")
```

`number` is defined in the (local) scope of the `guess_number` function, but not in the global scope. To reference `number` in the global scope, `number` first needs to be bound to a value accessible from the global scope, and (local variables from a function are not accessible. See the LEGB rules, below.)

Reference:

- [Python's LEGB rule regarding scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/190597)

Answer (score 0):

The variable "number" in your function "guess_number" is only local to that function. To fix your problem, you have to assign a variable "number" to the result from "guess_number". Thus, change

```
guess_number("Noam","Male")
```

to

```
number = guess_number("Noam","Male")
```